# No such table error when opening SQLite database from external storage Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to open and perform queries on a SQLite database that is stored in external storage.

I'm opening the database using the following piece of code.

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH+"/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

However whenever I run this I get the `no such table` error even though the table does exist in the database. As the database isn't stored in the assets folder I assume you don't have to copy the database before you can read it but I might be wrong.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BB2SoulDatabase.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SoulInfoDatabase"
                + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SoulInfoDatabase";
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you haven't placed the database in the assets folder?

Comment: I download the database each time the app is loaded, I would love to put it in the assets folder but I can't as you cant write to the assets at runtime

Comment: But you can copy you database from the assets to the sdcard and do stuff at runtime

Comment: That's true but at runtime is when I download the database. The database only exists when the app starts up as the database I'm downloading changes constantly

Comment: @M0rty when you want update a database you either uninstall the current app you have to remove the old database and attach a newer version of database file, or you can use the onupgrade method on the helper then add the column or table you just added

Comment: What happens is that it doesn't find the database and creates a new one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase(). The newly created one is obviously empty and therefore you'll get the mentioned error. There could me different reasons why it doesn't find the db, my guess would be permissions but that depends a lot on the Android version you're using. You might have to read up on this; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html. Apps don't get access to every directory on ext storage any more...

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way then, would anyone know a better solution than downloading the database to external storage each time? The datbase changes regularly so storing it manually in the assets folder won't work as I would have to update the app everytime there is a change to the database.

Comment: How about downloading the data e.g. as a JSON stream and create the database on the fly? You say you need the db only when the app starts so the question is, do you need the database at all? DBs are usually long term storage but this doesn't seem to be the case here?

Comment: That may work, I will look into it. I just find it strange that I can't read the database straight from external storage, seems simple enough, I guess not in practice though.